# LINQ statements in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, linq

For my class project I have to create a gradebook and write LINQ statements to list all the students, display in ascending order, and display everyone who passed the test.  All my statements are returning the same information which shouldn't be the case.  Here is my code.

```
Public Class GradeBook
Private nameValue As String
Private scoreValue As Integer
Public Sub New(ByVal n As String, ByVal s As Integer)
    nameValue = n
    scoreValue = s
End Sub
Public Property Name() As String
    Get
        Return nameValue
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        nameValue = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Score() As Integer
    Get
        Return scoreValue
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        scoreValue = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Sub displayGradeBook()
    Console.WriteLine("Name: " & Name & vbTab & "Score: " & Score)
End Sub

End Class

 Sub Main()
    Dim g1 As New GradeBook("AAA", 70)
    Dim g2 As New GradeBook("BBB", 50)
    Dim g3 As New GradeBook("CCC", 100)
    Dim g4 As New GradeBook("DDD", 80)
    'add g1, g2, g3 and g4 in a array and display all student scores 
    Dim gradeBooks As GradeBook() = {g1, g2, g3, g4}
    display(gradeBooks, "Scores for all students: ")

    'create a LINQ which get all scores in ascending order and display them.
    Dim ascending =
        From value In gradeBooks
        Order By value Ascending
        Select value
    display(gradeBooks, "Ascending Order")


    'create a LINQ which get all students who passed the exam
    Dim passed =
        From gradeBook In gradeBooks
        Where gradeBook.Score > 60
        Order By gradeBook
        Select gradeBook
    display(passed, "Students who passed: ")



    'display number of passed students, their names and scores  




End Sub


'display gradeBook's information 
Private Sub display(ByVal gradeBooks As IEnumerable, ByVal header As String)
    Console.WriteLine(header)
    For Each g As GradeBook In gradeBooks
        g.displayGradeBook()
    Next
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 2):

Implements the interface Icomparable, and change display(gradeBooks, "Ascending Order") to display(ascending, "Ascending Order").

this code is working for me.

```
Module Module1


    Public Class GradeBook
        Implements IComparable(Of GradeBook)

        Private nameValue As String
        Private scoreValue As Integer
        Public Sub New(ByVal n As String, ByVal s As Integer)
            nameValue = n
            scoreValue = s
        End Sub
        Public Property Name() As String
            Get
                Return nameValue
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                nameValue = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property Score() As Integer
            Get
                Return scoreValue
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Integer)
                scoreValue = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Public Sub displayGradeBook()
            Console.WriteLine("Name: " & Name & vbTab & "Score: " & Score)
        End Sub

        Public Function CompareTo(ByVal other As GradeBook) As Integer Implements System.IComparable(Of GradeBook).CompareTo
            '-1 = less than other; 0 = same as other; +1 = greater than other'
            If IsNothing(other) Then
                Return 1
            End If

            If Me.Score > other.Score Then
                Return 1
            End If

            If Me.Score < other.Score Then
                Return -1
            End If

            Return 0


        End Function

    End Class

    Sub Main()
        Dim g1 As New GradeBook("AAA", 70)
        Dim g2 As New GradeBook("BBB", 50)
        Dim g3 As New GradeBook("CCC", 100)
        Dim g4 As New GradeBook("DDD", 80)
        'add g1, g2, g3 and g4 in a array and display all student scores 
        Dim gradeBooks As GradeBook() = {g1, g2, g3, g4}
        display(gradeBooks, "Scores for all students: ")

        'create a LINQ which get all scores in ascending order and display them.
        Dim ascending =
            From value In gradeBooks
            Order By value Ascending
            Select value
        display(ascending, "Ascending Order")


        'create a LINQ which get all students who passed the exam
        Dim passed =
            From gradeBook In gradeBooks
            Where gradeBook.Score > 60
            Order By gradeBook
            Select gradeBook

        display(passed, "Students who passed: ")



        'display number of passed students, their names and scores  




    End Sub


    'display gradeBook's information 
    Private Sub display(ByVal gradeBooks As IEnumerable, ByVal header As String)
        Console.WriteLine(header)
        For Each g As GradeBook In gradeBooks
            g.displayGradeBook()
        Next
        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Thanks.  Can't believe I didn't see that.

Answer (score 0):

For the order by Score you need to request ordering by Score

```
Dim ordered =
    From value In gradeBooks
    Order By value.Score
    Select value
display(ordered, "Ascending Order")
```

(I have also changed the name of the IEnumerable to avoid confusion with the keyword Ascending)

The same change is required also in the extraction of the passed enumerable

```
Dim passed =
    From gradeBook In gradeBooks
    Where gradeBook.Score > 60
    Order By gradeBook.Score
    Select gradeBook
display(passed, "Students who passed: ")
```

Your actual code is passing a whole gradebook as object to order by. In this way you need to implement (as explained in other answer) the IEnumerable interface to teach the compiler how it should compare a gradebook against another gradebook to order them. But probably this is not really needed here and simply passing the field (numeric or string) to order by is enough

Answer (score 0):

The reason you were seeing the same information repeated, is you were calling display on the same collection twice.  Once that is corrected you should get an exception thrown, because you're trying to orderby whole objects instead of a property/field of the objects.